Alternative to a shadow
For forms, we use sticky button bars at the bottom of the browser. This increased the conversion.
The sticky bar has a shadow effect to make it clear that the user can scroll further down.
In some user tests, however, users thought that the shadow effect meant that the button bar was something separate and not part of the form.
Do you have an idea how to show that the button bar is sticky but part of the form?


"In some user tests, however, users thought that the shadow effect meant that the button bar was something separate and not part of the form." - Afterwards, did they realize it is part of the form? Were they hesistant / refused to click the buttons? There is really not much else in the page to "submit" the form, so I'm thinking you are hearing first reactions only and not a real problem.


First of all, I would remove the shadow of the button: the shadow of the form goes up, suggesting a lower light while the shadow of the button has a top left light, it's a contradiction, graphically it's a nonsense.
I would integrate the buttons into the form without ignoring the
shadow of the sticky bar
It would incorporate a form continuation indicator button. Assuming the hidden part of the form is interpretable only with a shadow is overestimating the users' perception capacity.



The main problem is the width of the sticky bar. It looks like a website footer.

[...] Users spend most of their time on other sites. This means that users prefer your site to work the same way as all the other sites they already know. Design for patterns for which users are accustomed.

Citation taken from https://www.nngroup.com/videos/jakobs-law-internet-ux/
The footer is much wider than the form, so it has no connection with the form and people do not associate it with each other. This leads to the obvious solution to make it the same width:

But even smaller is also a possibility:

Or floating buttons:

